# Cвязка Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 7.0

Tags: apache, tomcat

Доброго всем времени суток! В интернете много примеров настройки этой связки, но или я дуб, или что-то ещё (скорее всего 1-е) и у меня ничего не получается.

Есть у меня `appname.war`, установил `apache`, ну и `tomcat`. Просто запустить `war` на `tomcat` никакой проблемы не вызывает. А вот как через `apache` всё это провернуть, прошу помочь в этом разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

[Proxy Support HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/proxy-howto.html)

В 2-х словах:

1. Ставишь mod_proxy на apache

   a2enmod mod_proxy

   a2enmod mod_proxy_http
2. В конфиге apacha прописываешь ProxyPass. Например в файл sites-available/default

   <VirtualHost *:80> 
               ServerName paris 
               DocumentRoot /var/www/   
               ProxyPass         /app  http://paris:8080/app 
               ProxyPassReverse  /app  http://paris:8080/app 
               ProxyPreserveHost On 
   </VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

В инсталяторе IDE NetBeans можно выбрать установку ApacheTomcat. Я так понимаю нужно запускать JavaEE приложения, ну NetBeans под это и заточен как раз. Заодно можете посмотреть конфиги и пошариться в админке работающего ApacheTomcat.Скачать пакет устанвоки можно тут http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

p.s.При желании можно не ставить ничего кроме ApacheTomcat сервера.

Comment: Я, по-моему, написал, что запустить томкат проблем не вызывает, а вот c apache httpd server b apache tomcat - 2 разные вещи.